# How to select templates when using the Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Installation class?

Tags: c#, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I'm setting up a Web API project that uses Azure Push Notifications. I'd like to use the new "Installation" model instead of the older "Registration" model. The documentation is a bit limited however.

Looking at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.installation.tags.aspx#P:Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Installation.Tags), `Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Installation` has a `Tags` property.

There is also has a `Templates` [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.installation.templates.aspx#P:Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Installation.Templates). The template type is `InstallationTemplate` and [surprisingly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.installationtemplate.tags.aspx#P:Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.InstallationTemplate.Tags) also has `Tags`.

The templates are not just a list but a dictionary that maps from `string` to `InstallationTemplate`.

I understand the idea behind tags. But I'm confused about the two tag properties and the key of the dictionary.

I saw an example where the `Installation.Tag`is set to "foo" and then two templates are added with the keys "template1" and "template2". The `InstallationTemplate.Tag` was set to "tag-for-template1" and "tag-for-template2".

- Do the two tag values have to match?
- What is each of them used for?
- What should the key of the template dictionary be?
- If I use the method to send a notification via the NotificationHubClient, I can specify a tag - what is it matched against and which template will be picked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some testing I'm a bit wiser.

Both, the `Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Installation`'s tags *and* the tags inside of the `InstallationTemplate` will be evaluated when using `SendTemplateNotificationAsync()`. The key that has to be specified in the dictionary seems to be unused.

**Example:**

```
var installationA = new Installation();
installationA.Tags = new List<string> { $"install-a" };
installationA.Templates.Add("someKey", new InstallationTemplate
{
    Body = "JSON-FOR-TEMPLATE"
    Tags = new List<string> { $"subtemplate1" }
});
installationA.Templates.Add("someOtherKey", new InstallationTemplate
{
    Body = "JSON-FOR-TEMPLATE"
    Tags = new List<string> { $"subtemplate2" }
});


var installationB = new Installation();
installationB.Tags = new List<string> { $"install-b" };
installationB.Templates.Add("someKey", new InstallationTemplate
{
    Body = "JSON-FOR-TEMPLATE"
    Tags = new List<string> { $"subtemplate1" }
});
installationB.Templates.Add("someOtherKey", new InstallationTemplate
{
    Body = "JSON-FOR-TEMPLATE"
    Tags = new List<string> { $"subtemplate2" }
});
```

Using tag expressions you can now filter for any combination of "install-a", "install-b", "subtemplate1" and "subtemplate2".

The keys "someKey" and "someOtherKey" will not be used by the query and I don't understand why they did not use a `List<T>` instead of the dictionary.

Comment: Update: the `Tags` property inside the `InstallationTemplate` type has been marked as deprecated.